# Eloquent Order By alphabetically doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Here is a very simple line of code I am running:

```
return User::orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->get();
```

I expect to get the returned result in alphabetical order. Here is what I get:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "first_name": "Kousha",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "10",
    "first_name": "Monica",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "9",
    "first_name": "Alex",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "first_name": "Ali",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "7",
    "first_name": "Chris",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "5",
    "first_name": "Amin",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "6",
    "first_name": "Felix",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "8",
    "first_name": "Aleksi",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "first_name": "Ryan",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "first_name": "Paul",
    ...
}
```

If I try the order in descending order, I get another gibberish result. The only thing the order works for is the `id`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a conflicting "orderBy" attrbute defined in the User model?

Comment: @iavery, no I don't have a column called `orderBy` in this table.

Comment: @iavery, oh damn I think I realized the mistake. I encrypt the names in the database for privacy reasons. I think the `orderBy` is then running on the encrypted data and then the data is decrypted.

Comment: Well, that answers that, then! :) What I actually meant was that if you have the following line in your app/models/User.php file, it defines the default "orderBy" behavior for any User queries: protected $orderBy = 'first_name'; But I'm glad you solved it!

Comment: @iavery, oh I see! Well good to know that for future reference!!